# Why did my reputation not increase?

Tags: support, reputation

Recently I answered [this](https://superuser.com/questions/644690/why-is-hibernation-still-used/644696#644696) question. The votes didn't add to my reputation. In the answer you can see 23 upvotes, but I got only 210 reputation.

I added screenshots for better clarification:

[image]

---

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: I do believe you get a shiny badge for your 1st, 150th and 200th days of repcaps - also see [John Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and [John Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek its nice thanks for pointing it out,i cant get shiny badge,what is it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/badges/43/mortarboard?userid=148414 there you go!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek wow thanks for pointing out,my fav answer of meta.se is this one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174863/whats-the-feeling-of-having-more-than-10k-points-of-rep/174873#174873

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our [help center](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day.

So this is not a bug. Only reputation from accepted answers (+15) does not count towards the daily limit. You will not get any more reputation for today (based on UTC time). Any upvotes (or other means of getting reputation) will not count today. You'll have to wait until tomorrow.